# Remote login to specific computer (hostname) within a company network with 1 IP

Tags: ssh, vnc

I want to SSH or VNC to my computer in the company network. I know the internal IP (e.g. 192.168.x.x), the external IP name, and my computer's hostname.

if I do ssh username@externalIP

or open vnc://externalIP

How would ssh know which computer to go to on the network? Is there some way to indicate this?

If I ask my company to open port 22 would that be enough (or is vnc another port?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking has a fairly simple solution actually. Basically the computer you are trying to connect with must **allow `ssh`** and **the router must also have an open port** like you mentioned. If you are trying to access the computer from an external network (i.e. not your company's network),  then they may require a VPN. [What's a VPN?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DhYeqgufYss)

My university, for example, denies all requests from outside the network. You can't even ping our Raspberry Pi's from off-campus ;) In order to `ssh` or `ping` them, we have to connect with the provided VPN. It a powerful way to connect to internal, secured networks. Downside is you will probably need to contact IT within your company.

Comment: I just tried with the vnc command (which works fine in the building), but now it gives me 'Unable to communicate with “x.x.x.x”.  Make sure the remote computer is available and the firewall is not blocking screen sharing. Maybe there is a port I should open first (I can ask IT to do this). I'm trying to login to an iMac.

Comment: Possibly. If you can usually use VNC from within the building to connect to the computer, then it should work assuming that you connected to the VPN first.

Comment: Another problem: what if I want to access a page from the webserver. I can't expect people to have a vpn...

Comment: The solution is that I had to connect the computer through ethernet instead of wifi in order for vpn to work. Then your method works great!